# Python code for printing Mandelbrot set

Tags: python-3.x, math, tkinter, mandelbrot

I am trying to print the Mandelbrot set in the following code but it print half screen white and half black. I have gone through the code many times but I don't know where I am going wrong. Can someone please help

```
from tkinter import *

size = 400
black = "#000000"
window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width=size, height=size, bg="white")
canvas.pack()
img = PhotoImage(width=size, height=size)
canvas.create_image((size/2, size/2), image=img, state="normal")

# constants:
MaxValue = 4
MaxIterations = 50
planeWidth = 4

for x in range(0, size):
    for y in range(0, size): # for each pixel do:
        cReal = (x * planeWidth / size) - 2
        cImg =  (y * planeWidth / size) - 2
        zReal = 0
        zImg = 0
        count = 0
        while (zReal*zReal + zImg*zImg) <= MaxValue and count < MaxIterations:
            temp = (zReal * zReal) - (zImg * zImg) + cReal
            zImg = 2 * zReal * zImg * cImg
            zReal = temp
            count += 1

        if count == MaxIterations:
            img.put(black, (x,y))

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your update step:

```
            temp = (zReal * zReal) - (zImg * zImg) + cReal
            zImg = 2 * zReal * zImg * cImg
            zReal = temp
```

Specifically, the `* cImg` at the end of the line updating `zImg` should be `+ cImg`.

Once you do that, it makes a nice little Mandlebrot picture.

Comment: That could depend on the python version, the division `x * planeWidth / size` of all integer factors may result in python 2 only in the integer values `-2,-1,0,1`.

Comment: Thank you! that fixed it

Comment: @LutzL I assumed python 3 since the tags said that, but yes. Changing the `planeWidth` to `4.0` might be a good idea just to be safe.